# cannot bind scroll event to an div which has been created from ajax sucess

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code - where I have created a new div using ajax. name of div is

```
$('#section_product_listing_Csearch_ss').html(html);
```

The code for ajax call is given below

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "_ajax_files/product_listing_Csearch-ss_ajax.php,
dataType: "html",
success: function(html){ $('#section_product_listing_Csearch_ss').html(html);
} });
```

I cannot bind the scroll event to object

```
#section_product_listing_Csearch_ss
```

I have tried everything as described below by adding it inside ajax `success`; after the line of `$('#section_product_listing_Csearch_ss').html(html);`

```
1.) var newnode = $(html);  $newnode.find('#section_product_listing_Csearch_ss').scroll(function(){alert("hi");});

2.) $(window).on('scroll', '#section_product_listing_Csearch_ss',function(){
            alert("hi");});

3.) $("#section_product_listing_Csearch_ss").bind('scroll', function(){
            alert("hi"); }); 

4.) $(html).scroll(function(){ alert("hi");});

5.)$(html).bind('scroll', function(){ alert("scrolling");});          

6.) $('#section_product_listing_Csearch_ss').append('<div class="myDivx"></div>'); 

listenForScrollEvent($(".myDivx"));


function listenForScrollEvent(el){
    el.on("scroll", function(){
        el.trigger("custom-scroll");
    })
}


$("body").on("custom-scroll", ".myDiv", function(){
    console.log("Scrolled :P");
})
```

Comment: please check `"_ajax_files/product_listing_Csearch-ss_ajax.php` the double quote(") is not closed properly

Comment: Dear Sasidhar, thanks for your reply. the quotes had been completed and ajax is working. The section #section_product_listing_Csearch_ss in php page gets populated.

Comment: the problem is that I cannot bind a scroll event to this html section inside the php page.

Comment: your help would be much appreciated

Comment: hello @Binu http://jsfiddle.net/sasi2191/a41nm8kt/, Please check this

Comment: Dear Sasidhar, could you please check the link : http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/xnq3-fc0y

Comment: Hello @Binu, Please check this link : http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/3czk-03bh